# Blazor Cannot read the property parentnode of undefined

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

In the below code, when I click the button, instead of appearing a hello text, it throws an exception: Cannot read the property parentnode of undefined. I know that I can solve it in many ways but what's the reason of this? why is this occurring?

```
@page "/"

@{
    void click()
    {
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    }
}

<button @onclick="click">Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to do this is

```
@page "/"

@if (ShowH1)
{
  <h1>Hello</h1>
}

<button @onclick="Click">Click me!</button>

@code
{
  bool ShowH1 = false;

  void Click()
  {
    ShowH1 = !ShowH1;
  }
}
```

The reason your code doesn't work is that all mark-up in your .razor file (outside of `@code`) is transpiled into C#, overriding `BuildRenderTree`.

`BuildRenderTreee` is passed a parameter `RenderTreeBuilder __builder` to render to. Your method is being transpiled as an embedded method, like this

```
protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder __builder)
{
    void click()
    {
        __builder.AddMarkupContent(0, "\t\t");
        __builder.AddMarkupContent(1, "<h1>Hello</h1>\r\n");
    }

    __builder.AddMarkupContent(2, "\r\n");
    __builder.OpenElement(3, "button");
    __builder.AddAttribute(4, "onclick", ... call our click method));
    __builder.AddContent(5, "Click me!");
    __builder.CloseElement();
}
```

So here you see that the button calls our embedded `click` method, which has captured the `__builder` parameter that was passed at the point the component was rendering.

But the __builder was only valid at the point it was rendering. By the time your user clicks the button the __builder is now invalid, and yet your code executes `__builder.AddMarkupContent(....)` on it - and therefore causes an exception.

Comment: I knew this way and I didn't ask for the solution. I just want to know why this exception is happening.

Comment: @MahanLameie Answer updated to include why your example cannot work.

Comment: That's what  I need. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax and the way is incorrect. Try this one.

```
@page "/"
<h1>@text</h1>

<button @onclick="@click">Click me</button>

@code 
{
     private string text;

     private void click()
     {
          text = "Hello";
     }
}
```

Comment: I knew this way and I didn't ask for the solution. I just want to know why this exception is happening.

Comment: Because the part of code that starts with '@code' includes C# code. But your click method is including html code. It is so strange not getting error when you build your code, there should be error like "Error CS0103 The name '__builder' does not exist in the current context"